# Subproccessing with a for loop

Tags: python, for-loop, subprocess

I have this program that parses through a filepath and gets all files ending in a certain ending. Then I have to use a subproccess with these lists are created to run msbuild and print the results.

```
MSprompt = 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\\v4.0.30319\\MSBuild.exe'                                   #MSPrompt is the string that is used w/ the subprocess function to open up MSBuild and run it correctly
MSfilename= "C:\\Users\\bgbesase\\Documents\\Brent\\Code\\Visual Studio\\" 

def getUnitTest(path):
    foundFiles = []
    foundPathUpToUnitTests = []

    for r,d,f in os.walk(path):
        for files in f:
            if files.endswith('.UnitTests.vbproj'):
                path2 = os.path.split(files)
                #print path2
                foundFiles.append(path2)
            for lines in path2:
                if lines.endswith('.vbproj'):
                    s = lines.strip('vbproj')
                    print s
                    foundPathUpToUnitTests.append(s)

    foundFiles=  [str(value[1]) for value in foundFiles]
    return foundFiles

    foundFiles2 = [ str(value for value in file if value) for file in foundFiles]                   
    print foundFiles2
    return foundPathUpToUnitTests
```

FoundFiles is the a list that is made up of tuples of filenames ending in '.UnitTests.vbproj'

```
foundFiles = [
bb.APDS.UnitTests.vbproj
bb.DatabaseAPI.UnitTests.vbproj
bb.DataManagement.UnitTests.vbproj
bb.FormControls.UnitTests.vbproj
bb.Geometry.UnitTests.vbproj ]
```

foundPathUpToUnitTests is a list that is the same values in foundFiles just without the vb.proj part.

```
foundPathUpToUnitTests = [
bb.APDS.UnitTests.
bb.DatabaseAPI.UnitTests.
bb.DataManagement.UnitTests.
bb.FormControls.UnitTests. ]
```

The function I have for the subproccess is this:

```
def runMSBuild(foundFiles2, foundPathUpToUnitTests):
    p = subprocess.Popen([msprompt, MSfilename + foundFiles2 + "\\" + foundPathUpToUnitTests], shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT)
    for line in p.stdout.readlines():
        print line,
    retval = p.wait()
```

When I run it normally with MSpromt and MSFilename it works, however what I need to do is create a loop getting the first value from foundFiles, and foundPathUpToUnitTests and use concatenation to get the correct filepath so MSBuild can run properly, and I have no clue how to do this. Any help would be greatly appreciated I've stuck on this for awhile now, thanks in advance!

Comment: Please take more care about the formatting of your post and the indenting of your code which is essential in Python.

Comment: @glglgl there, I fixed it :)

Comment: The indentation is not what you want, and most likely not what you have. You would get exceptions any time your first file does not end in `.UnitTests.vbproj`. Other point, do you need the names in `foundPathUpToUnitTests` to end in `.`?

Comment: @ThomasFenzl No they don't have to end in `.` but but I've already tested the data just by hardcoding it and the `.`  doesn't matter if it's there or not.

Comment: You haven't fixed the indentation

Comment: There are numerous issues in your code unrelated to `subprocess` module e.g., `str.strip()` usage (I assume your actual code is correctly indented).